Sorting results from Left JOIN in SQLite
I'm using better-sqlite-3 in a SvelteKit app. I have two tables, one for customers and one for favorites, the user can set a customer to favorite, and the info are saved in app_users_favorites, where favorite_id corresponds to the key id (called 'chiave') column of the customer's table.
app_users_favorites (
    database_id TEXT,
    user_id TEXT,
    favorite_id TEXT,
);

This is the customer statement, used for an infinite scrolling page. There is a column called preferito (favorite) that is null, it is changed by looking at the favorite table, if the chiave (key) id is in the corresponding row, then set preferito to 1 or 0. As of now it works, but the sorting does not. If sorting by preferito, I excpect all the favorite customers to appear at the top or bottom of the list based on ASC or DESC. However the sorting for favorite does not work, it does for every other value, so I think it must be how I operate on the preferito field.
  getClifor_gen_paginated_search: (
    database_id,
    tipo_clifor,
    searchQuery,
    limit,
    offset,
    orderBy,
    sortDirection,
    user_id
  ) => {
    const validColumns = [
      "rag_soc",
      "cod_clifor",
      "bloccato",
      "preferito",
      "categoria",
      "macrocategoria",
      "sottocategoria",
      "citta",
      "data_ult_ordine",
      "data_ult_doc_ft",
      "data_ult_doc_no_ft",
      "des_raggr1",
      "des_raggr2",
      "des_raggr3",
    ];
    const validDirections = ["ASC", "DESC"];

    // Validate orderBy and sortDirection
    if (!validColumns.includes(orderBy)) {
      throw new Error(`Invalid column name: ${orderBy}`);
    }
    if (!validDirections.includes(sortDirection)) {
      throw new Error(`Invalid sort direction: ${sortDirection}`);
    }

    // Construct the query
    let orderByClause = "";

    if (orderBy === "preferito") {
      orderByClause = `
        ORDER BY preferito ${sortDirection}, rag_soc ASC
        `;
    } else if (orderBy === "bloccato") {
      orderByClause = `
        ORDER BY bloccato ${sortDirection}, preferito DESC, rag_soc ASC
        `;
    } else if (orderBy === "cod_clifor") {
      const reversedSortDirection = sortDirection === "ASC" ? "DESC" : "ASC";
      orderByClause = `
          ORDER BY CAST(cod_clifor AS SIGNED) ${reversedSortDirection}, preferito DESC
          `;
    } else if (orderBy === "rag_soc") {
      const reversedSortDirection = sortDirection === "ASC" ? "DESC" : "ASC";
      orderByClause = `
        ORDER BY rag_soc ${reversedSortDirection}, preferito DESC
        `;
    } else if (
      orderBy === "data_ult_ordine" ||
      orderBy === "data_ult_doc_ft" ||
      orderBy === "data_ult_doc_no_ft"
    ) {
      orderByClause = `
        ORDER BY 
          SUBSTR(${orderBy}, 5, 4) || '-' || SUBSTR(${orderBy}, 3, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR(${orderBy}, 1, 2) ${sortDirection},
          rag_soc ASC
          `;
    }

    const query = `
      SELECT 
        clifor_gen.*, 
        CASE 
          WHEN app_users_favorites.favorite_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END AS preferito
      FROM 
        clifor_gen
      LEFT JOIN 
        app_users_favorites 
        ON clifor_gen.database_id = app_users_favorites.database_id 
        AND app_users_favorites.user_id = ?
        AND app_users_favorites.favorite_id = clifor_gen.chiave
      WHERE 
        clifor_gen.database_id = ? 
        AND clifor_gen.tipo_clifor = ?
        AND (
          clifor_gen.rag_soc LIKE ? 
          OR clifor_gen.cod_clifor LIKE ? 
          OR clifor_gen.categoria LIKE ? 
          OR clifor_gen.macrocategoria LIKE ? 
          OR clifor_gen.sottocategoria LIKE ? 
          OR clifor_gen.citta LIKE ? 
          OR clifor_gen.des_raggr1 LIKE ? 
          OR clifor_gen.des_raggr2 LIKE ? 
          OR clifor_gen.des_raggr3 LIKE ?
        )
      ${orderByClause}
      LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
    `;

    const stmt = db.prepare(query);

    return stmt.all(
      user_id,  // user_id for checking if the item is favorited
      database_id,
      tipo_clifor,
      `%${searchQuery}%`,
      `%${searchQuery}%`,
      `%${searchQuery}%`,
      `%${searchQuery}%`,
      `%${searchQuery}%`,
      `%${searchQuery}%`,
      `%${searchQuery}%`,
      `%${searchQuery}%`,
      `%${searchQuery}%`,
      limit,
      offset
    );
  },
};


Use a sub-query and then sort on that.  eg.  SELECT * FROM ( SELECT fields FROM something WHERE whatever) ORDER BY whatever LIMIT a OFFSET b  etc.

@Keith thak you! If you want to submit an example I'll mark it as solution.
